# Do you have to join tables "ON" fields or can you just equate them in there where clause?

Tags: mysql, join

We have been doing queries a bunch of different ways and queries have been working when we do a

```
SELECT t.thing FROM table1 t JOIN table2 s WHERE t.something = s.somethingelse AND t.something = 1
```

and it worked with all queries except one. This one query was hanging forever and crashes our server, but it apparently works if we do it like:

```
SELECT t.thing FROM table1 t JOIN table2 s ON t.something = s.somethingelse WHERE t.something = 1
```

We are trying to figure out if the problem is due to the query structure or due to some corruption in the account we are trying to query.

Is the first syntax correct? Thanks.

Comment: I think if you do the first one, you don't want the join keyword.  Just separate the two tables with a comma.  I'm not sure WHAT it would do if you said JOIN but not provide the ON portion.  I would have thought it would give you a syntax error.

Comment: FWIW, every time you list out tables in the FROM and "join" in the WHERE, God kills a kitten.

Comment: @Derek: also, the terrorists win

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ON clause. Though you can also join with commas, e.g.:  SELECT * FROM table1, table2;

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ANSI formats.. you can use

```
Select ...
   from tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1.fld = tbl2.fld
```

OR

```
select ...
   from tbl1, tbl2
   where tbl1.fld = tbl2.fld...
```

The explicit join is the more common format where you are explicitly showing developers after yourself how the tables are related without respect to filtering criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Your first syntax miss the ON.  When you join it is mandatory to tell ON what fields the join is happening.

I would recommend using JOIN ON over WHERE to do your joins.

1) your where clause will be easier to read since it will not be pollute by join where clause.
2) your join section is easier to read and understand.

We all agree both method works, but the JOIN one is better due to theses points.

my 2 cents